# In a gem or lib, where should I create a sub-project that's closely related to a gem?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, naming-conventions, ruby-3

Let's say, I want to add a code-autogenerator for my gem/library. A code generator won't be a single executive cli file, but it'll contain source code as well as a cli file, and I'll be working on it too along with the main gem. Besides, it'll be written in a different language. I could move it into a different repository, but for now I've chosen to use a single repository. **According to the convention,** in what sub-directory in the main repository should I create that sub-project? opt, var, extra, tools....?

Answer (score 0):

There is more likely no convention for a such situation and I think you already know the actually good solution: use a separate repository.

If this solution is not acceptable for now, a good option would be to put it in the folder with a name explaining its purpose. E.g. if it's a code generator, it could be inside "code_generator" or "tools/code_generator".